# Can't convert from void to bool compile error

Tags: c#, .net

I am having some trouble with visual studio, as it says it won't compile. I can't figure out what the problem is. it says something like it can't convert from void to bool, even though there is no 'bool'. Here is my code:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication14
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myFunction(14));
        }

        public static void myFunction(int x)
        {
            return x + 2;
        }
    }
```

What is causing that compile error?

Comment: `myFunction` should return an int.

Comment: The WriteLine() meth is is trying to output a value, but myFunction isn't returning a value (the return value is 'void').

Comment: Please take the [tour] and visit [ask] as well as the [checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Your question isn't particular well asked and deserves a better title. After that I guess it is also a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
class Program
{
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
           Console.WriteLine(myFunction(14));
     }

     public static int myFunction(int x)
     {
           return x + 2;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning an Int. Void has no return type. To make this work you will need

```
public static int myFunction(int x)
{
    return x + 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The type `void` indicates that a mamber does not return anything. So when your method is marked as such it should not return a value. However when you call `Console.WriteLine` you need a value to be printed to the console.

Furthermore your method should make a calculation and return something - in your case an `int`. So instead of defining your method as `void` let it return an `int`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(myFunction(14));
    }

    public static int myFunction(int x)
    {
        return x + 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `myfunction` method your returning some int value but `myfunction` return type is `void` in your code. Plaese change `void` to `int` and the application will work.

```html
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int myFunction(int x)
        {
            return x + 2;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myFunction(14));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```